# Mass file renaming in Bash but keeping a section of the file name

Tags: command-line, bash, rename, batch-rename

I have a large number of .jpg file that have extraneous data ahead of a file id that i need to have removed to better set up my file structure for a later project. How can I do a batch rename in either command line or Bash (bash is preferable)

Example:
A_file_name_f3xe3_1_60113520.jpg - (60113520 being the ID)
To Become:
60113520.jpg

All files have underscores before the ID, but there are randomly placed extra underscores elsewhere in the name.

Answer (score 4):

There's a command especially suited for this :

```
rename -n 's/.*?(\d+.jpg$)/$1/' *.jpg
```

It's `prename` on `debian` and derivated, and it's a `perl` executable.

Remove `-n` switch if your test fit your needs.

To make it the default one (still `debian` and derivated  :

```
 update-alternatives --set rename /usr/bin/prename
```

Comment: Nema wrote that *there are randomly placed extra underscores elsewhere in the name*, indicating no consistent file name prefix before the ID.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
for FILE in *.jpg ; do mv -v "$FILE" "${FILE//*_/}" ; done
```

This removes everything in JPG file names up to and including the last underscore in the file name. It is described [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) in section *Substring Replacement*:

> ${string//substring/replacement}
>
> > Replace all matches of *`$substring`* with *`$replacement`*.

In your case, *`replacement`* is empty.

Comment: this works perfect in my case, but how to make it recursevly?